# Update statement to update part of column length

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-update, substring

I'm working on SQL Server 2008. Assume the following column.

```
column1

cjd.001 306.1   
cjd.001 306.2   
cjd.001 306.R
```

Now i want to replace all '.' with '-'. But just from first string i.e. before space or below 8 characters. The remaining field should remain same.

```
SampleOutput

cjd-001 306.1   
cjd-001 306.2   
cjd-001 306.R
```

I tried below query but it replaces all '.'.

```
UPDATE dbo.table
SET column1 = REPLACE(column1, '.', '-')
```

I want to know what can i use in where clause?
Tried using substring function but it didn't work.

Comment: Obviously you must split your string in two parts and only change the first part. So start with trying to find the position where to split the string. Then use SUBSTRING accordingly, then REPLACE, then glue your two parts together again.

Comment: Is it always a single character at the fourth position that you end up replacing? As in your example data?

Comment: Can a space occur in position 1, and if so shall it prevent replacing at all or shall it be ignored or even removed?

Comment: No Martin '.' may occur at any place. But i just want to replace those occuring before first space

Comment: Space will not occur at first position Throsten.
Can you help me out with query sample of spliting string?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need a SQL like this:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET column1 = REPLACE(SUBSTRING(column1, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', column1)), '.', '-')
            + SUBSTRING(column1, CHARINDEX(' ', column1) + 1, LEN(column1));
```

[[SQL Fiddle Demo]](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f93b7/2)